# Download failed: Homebrew-installed `curl` is not installed

Tags: php, macos, xampp

command : `brew install php`

Every time I want to update php on Mac I always get an error like this:

```
Downloading https://www.freetds.org/files/stable/freetds-1.3.13.tar.bz2
Error: php: Failed to download resource "freetds"
Download failed: Homebrew-installed `curl` is not installed for: https://www.freetds.org/files/stable/freetds-1.3.13.tar.bz2
```

how to handle it ??

Comment: Can you try running `brew install curl` first?

Comment: For me it happen because of current Mac OS version. You can install php via macport and switch php version.

Comment: @sailaminoak, may I know which macOS version are you on? I am on Catalina facing the same issue.

Answer (score 15):

try

```
brew install curl
```

it's worked for me

Comment: On old version of macOS such as Big Sur, curl will not auto enabled, follow the instructions just after installation of  curl.

Answer (score 0):

`brew install curl`
then
`brew install composer`
just worked on my macOS Catalina 2013 Version 10.15.7