# Unable to install PHP due to Error: php: Failed to download resource "freetds"

Tags: php, macos, curl, installation, freetds

I am trying to install PHP on my M1 Macbook using homebrew. When I run `brew install php` I get the following error:

```
Error: php: Failed to download resource "freetds"
Download failed: Homebrew-installed `curl` is not installed for: https://www.freetds.org/files/stable/freetds-1.3.18.tar.bz2
```

I researched this issue and found another question addressing my specific issue:

[Download failed: Homebrew-installed `curl` is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679391/download-failed-homebrew-installed-curl-is-not-installed)

The only answer on this question says to install **curl**, so I ran `brew install curl` and let it run through a lengthy download and installation. Once this completed, I ran `brew install php` once again, but I am still getting the same error, so the solution in this question did not resolve my issue.

### Checking Curl

I figured that something must have gone wrong in the brew installation, so I ran it again and noticed this output at the very end:

```
==> Installing curl dependency: openssl@1.1
==> perl ./Configure --prefix=/Users/ciesinsg/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1u --openssldir=/Users/
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/ciesinsg/Library/Logs/Homebrew/openssl@1.1/02.make:
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/ciesinsg/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/ciesinsg/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1u/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/sha/sha1_one.d.tmp -MT crypto/sha/sha1_one.o -c -o crypto/sha/sha1_one.o crypto/sha/sha1_one.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/ciesinsg/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/ciesinsg/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1u/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/sha/sha1dgst.d.tmp -MT crypto/sha/sha1dgst.o -c -o crypto/sha/sha1dgst.o crypto/sha/sha1dgst.c
CC="clang" perl crypto/sha/asm/sha512-armv8.pl ios64 crypto/sha/sha256-armv8.S
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/ciesinsg/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/ciesinsg/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1u/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/sha/sha256.d.tmp -MT crypto/sha/sha256.o -c -o crypto/sha/sha256.o crypto/sha/sha256.c
CC="clang" perl crypto/sha/asm/sha512-armv8.pl ios64 crypto/sha/sha512-armv8.S
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/ciesinsg/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/ciesinsg/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1u/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF crypto/sha/sha512.d.tmp -MT crypto/sha/sha512.o -c -o crypto/sha/sha512.o crypto/sha/sha512.c
make[1]: /bin/sh: line 1:  1129 Killed: 9               mv crypto/seed/seed_ofb.d.tmp crypto/seed/seed_ofb.d
*** [crypto/sha/sha1_one.o] Killed: 9
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: error closing STDOUT:  at crypto/sha/asm/sha1-armv8.pl line 364.
*** [crypto/sha/sha1dgst.o] Killed: 9
make[1]: *** [crypto/sha/sha512.o] Killed: 9
make[1]: *** [crypto/sha/sha1-armv8.S] Error 255
make[1]: *** [crypto/seed/seed_ofb.o] Error 137
make: *** [all] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core!
```

I ran `curl --version` and saw that a version does appear to be installed:

```
curl 7.88.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0) libcurl/7.88.1 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/3.3.6 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.51.0
Release-Date: 2023-02-20
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL threadsafe UnixSockets
```

So I am not sure why it is failing to install freetds or why it is throwing the error about curl. Does anybody know what might be causing this?

### Additional Info:

Macbook Pro M2
MacOS: Ventura 13.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [posted](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4571) on the Homebrew discussion portal and received some help which resolved the issue:

First, run `brew doctor` to see if there's any kind of problem with the installation. In my case, due to security policies at my work, my IT team installed Homebrew in the wrong location, which resulted in the `brew doctor` output:

> Warning: Your Homebrew's prefix is not /opt/homebrew.

In my case, I had installed homebrew in `/home/homebrew` when **Apple Silicon** macs should install homebrew in `/home/opt/homebrew`. Please keep in mind that if you have an Intel mac, the installation location should instead be `/usr/local`. Regardless, as per the [docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#untar-anywhere-unsupported), you should install it in the correct location for the prefix to be correct and to avoid bugs.

During my reinstall, the security policies in my company limited my access to the `/opt/` folder which resulted in the error `/opt/homebrew is not writeable`. I was able to resolve this by changing ownership using `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /opt/homebrew`.

This finally let me complete the installation and ensure it was working out `/opt/homebrew`. Running `brew doctor` again resulted in the output:

> Your system is ready to brew.

The problem was immediately resolved and I can now install PHP without issues.